# VBA: Dynamic Adapting Scrollbar

Tags: vba, excel, scrollbar, userform

I have a user form containg a frame. During runtime, the user can add controls to this frame. Ultimately, the added controls can exceed the size of the frame. In this case I would like to increase the `insideheight` of the frame. So my vertical scrollbar does cover the whole area.

```
frm.ScrollHeight = .InsideHeight
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.InsideHeight` is not responsible for the scrollbar. However, the `.ScrollHeight` is. While adding new controls, this height must be increased.

When adding a new set of controls execute this:
Exchange `50` with the height of your control.

```
Dim scrHeight As Integer
With frm
    scrHeight = .ScrollHeight
    .ScrollHeight = scrHeight + 50
End With
```